# Django Cron, execute def from views

Tags: python, django, cron

I have a problem.
I needto implement a function that will be called cyclically
I have to call dashgenerate functions because it generates data records

this cron.py:

```
from django_cron import CronJobBase, Schedule
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404

class MyCronJob(CronJobBase):
    RUN_EVERY_MINS = 60
    schedule = Schedule(run_every_mins=RUN_EVERY_MINS)
    code = 'CRM.my_cron_job'
    def do(self):
        return redirect('dashboard/dashgenerate/')
```

dashgenerate is a def from another app in project:

```
def dashgenerate(request):
.....
```

Comment: why do you need to call view function?

Comment: this function "dashgenerate" generate records to data base, and I want him to do it every hour

Comment: you could write "task" function which does not expect request object as parameter. Although your view function updates database it does not have to be view, it can be normal python function

Comment: but this function also works when called via the appropriate button on the page

Comment: why don't you wrap functionality into separated function which can then be called from your "do" function in Cron or your view function?